# R and Sparklyr - unable to connect to spark

Tags: r

I Have the following code.

```
 #loading library
library(sparklyr)
library(tidyverse)


# Installing spark
spark_install(version = "2.4.3")

devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

am getting this error.
Using Spark: 2.4.3
Error in validate_java_version_line(master, version) : 
  Java version detected but couldn't parse version from: openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16

Kindly help.